# More efficient way of getting frequency of words

Tags: java, optimization

I want to count the frequency of each word in an ArrayList by the start of the word. e.g [cat, cog, mouse] will mean there are 2 words begining with **c** and one word begining with **m**. The code I have works fine but there are 26 letters in the alphabet which will require alot more **if** s. Is there any other way of doing this?

```
public static void  countAlphabeticalWords(ArrayList<String> arrayList) throws IOException
{
    int counta =0, countb=0, countc=0, countd=0,counte=0;
    String word = "";
    for(int i = 0; i<arrayList.size();i++)
    {

        word = arrayList.get(i);

          if (word.charAt(0) == 'a' || word.charAt(0) == 'A'){ counta++;}
          if (word.charAt(0) == 'b' || word.charAt(0) == 'B'){ countb++;}    

    }
    System.out.println("The number of words begining with A are: " + counta);
    System.out.println("The number of words begining with B are: " + countb);

}
```

Comment: Try Map . put the character as key and increment its value when it appear again.

Comment: That's not word frequency; that's "word starting with letter", a different thing.  Map is the answer for both.

Comment: btw, you should accept the answer that helped you most...

Answer (score 7):

### Use a Map

```
public static void  countAlphabeticalWords(List<String> arrayList) throws IOException {
  Map<Character,Integer> counts = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
  String word = "";

  for(String word : list) {
    Character c = Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0));
    if (counts.containsKey(c)) {
      counts.put(c, counts.get(c) + 1);
    }
    else {
      counts.put(c, 1);
    }
  }

  for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : counts.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("The number of words begining with " + entry.getKey() + " are: " + entry.getValue());
  }
```

### Or use a Map and AtomicInteger (as per Jarrod Roberson)

```
public static void  countAlphabeticalWords(List<String> arrayList) throws IOException {
  Map<Character,AtomicInteger> counts = new HashMap<Character,AtomicInteger>();
  String word = "";

  for(String word : list) {
    Character c = Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0));
    if (counts.containsKey(c)) {
      counts.get(c).incrementAndGet();
    }
    else {
      counts.put(c, new AtomicInteger(1));
    }
  }

  for (Map.Entry<Character, AtomicInteger> entry : counts.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("The number of words begining with " + entry.getKey() + " are: " + entry.getValue());
  }
```

### Best Practices

Never do `list.get(i)`, use `for(element : list)` instead. And never use `ArrayList` in a signature use the Interface `List` instead so you can change the implemenation.

Comment: using `AtomicInteger` would be more efficient as you can mutate it in place instead of creating a new `Integer` object every time you need to increment the count. It would make it thread safe as well.

Comment: Why should you always use `List` instead of `ArrayList` for the signature?

Comment: deezy : why force the calling code to use a specific list implementation? What if it uses a LinkedList for some reason? With ArrayList, you force the code to make a conversion before calling...

Comment: It's a correct solution, but considering efficiency, my will be quite faster. I made a simple testcase, see edit in my answer. I made it just out of curiosity, I don't say your solution is wrong :)

Comment: Thanks for the help :) I just have a few questions. See I have never used Map.

Comment: What do the following do. counts.put(c, counts.get(c) + 1); counts.put(c, 1); Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : counts.entrySet()) Thanks sorry for the extra comments.

Comment: To user2079139: a map is just a collection of <key, value> pairs, stored in such a way that it is easy to find a value thanks to a key. Here it is used to store pairs with the initial as the key and the number of occurrences as the value. The counts.put is used either to increment the number of occurrences, or to set it to 1 if it is the first time. The Map.Entry stuff is just getting all the pairs to proceed console output.

Answer (score 4):

How about this? Considering that the words start only with `[a-zA-Z]`:

```
public static int[] getCount(List<String> arrayList) {
    int[] data = new int[26];
    final int a = (int) 'a';

    for(String s : arrayList) {
        data[((int) Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(0))) - a]++;
    }

    return data;
}
```

**edit:**

**Just out of curiosity**, I made a very simple test comparing my method and Steph's method with map.
List with 236 items, 10000000 iterations (without printing the result): my code took ~10000ms and Steph's took ~65000ms.

Test: http://pastebin.com/HNBgKFRk

Data: http://pastebin.com/UhCtapZZ

Comment: Actually I like and upvoted your answer. In any case your solution will be slightly more efficient, as you never create Integer objects. But I still prefer my solution, except for really performance sensitive systems, because in yours you are obliged to make assumptions on the authorized initials ([a-zA-Z]), while I am not. I like generic solutions :)

Comment: Yea, you're right... It's just that he asked for efficient solution and mentioned that he needs only the basic 26 characters, so simple array lookup table was first thing that crossed my mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Now, every character can be cast to an integer, representing an ASCII decimal. For example, `(int)'a'` is 97. `'z'`'s ASCII decimal is 122. http://www.asciitable.com/

You can create a lookup table for the characters:

`int characters = new int[128]`

Then in your algorithm's loop use the ASCII decimal as index and increment the value:

```
word = arrayList.get(i);
characters[word.charAt(0)]++;
```

In the end, you can print the occurence of the characters:

```
for (int i = 97; i<=122; i++){
  System.out.println(String.format("The number of words beginning with %s are: %d", (char)i, characters[i]));
}
```